# Fix Power Functions cable near connector (L motor)

Tags: power-functions, repair

We have a broken cable on the power functions L motor. I've fixed an M-motor before in the engine, but this time the cut is near the connector.

Unlike the M-motor, this connector doesn't have the clips to open.
How can this connector be opened to shrink the wire?
The L-motor has a different connector than the M-motor, it looks like this:

[image: L motor connector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are no visible clips on the connector, it is probably not possible to open it without damaging it. Instead, you could purchase an [8886](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8886-1) or [8871](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8871-1) extension wire and use it to replace the entire cable (assuming you can open the motor).

Comment: It doesn't look like solid plastic completely, since there is a line halfway. I will try your solution, after which we won't have a need for the connector anymore, so we can destroy it to see if someone in the future can benefit of the knowledge.